# Google Play Store In App image purchasing

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have created a simple custom keyboard for Android. I also successfully created in-app purchasing for various features.

Now, I would like to include image packs (let's say 10 images in each pack) as in app purchases. Will Google hold these images as in-app purchases so that when purchased, I can download from Google Play to the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I would like to include image packs (let's say 10 images in each pack) as in app purchases. Will Google hold these images as in-app purchases so that when purchased, I can download from Google Play to the device?

**->NO** In-app purchase library only handles purchase flow

You have 2 options.

1. Put all of the Images in the app. Depending upon security and size of images, you can encrypt images so if anyone tries to extract it they will only get encrypted images. After purchase decrypt it and show it to user. Disadvantage of this approach is size of your apk will increase.
2. Implement a dedicated server for the images and download them once in-app purchase is complete. Disadvantage - you will have external server dependency in your app.

Hope Android will implement something which can be hosted on console, in future, expansion files are their but they are not suitable for in-app purchases. We use approach 1 most of times.